# Security in Java EE Application with JBoss

Tags: security, jboss, jakarta-ee

What would be the basic and obvious security considerations and recommendations in a Java EE Web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use HTTPS
- Use [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) to simplify some stuff.
- Limit external access point.
- Make sure you don't have a single point of failure.
- Make sure communication channels are properly secured when needed.
- Secure access to components by white list (give access instead of removing access).
- Make sure the state is kept on then server side.
- Test test test test test...
- [Keep updated on security flaws](http://secwatch.org/).
- The rest is all about good design.

Answer (score 1):

Don't trust anything that's not under your control.  The primary, most important aspect of this is: **Don't trust that the input to your POST/GET handlers will come from the forms you design.**

Validate all client input, especially before you use it to interact with SQL, HQL, other external data sources or the command line.